# Python Bytes to CTypes Void Pointer

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a c function that takes as arguments a void * pointer and an integer length for the size of the buffer pointed to.

e.g.

```
char* myfunc(void *mybuffer, int buflen)
```

On the python side I have a bytes object of binary data read from a file.

What I am trying to figure out is the right conversions to be able to call the c function from python, and am struggling a bit.

I understand the conversions for dealing with simple string data (e.g. encoding to utf-8 and using a char_p type) but dealing with a bytes object has been a bit of a struggle....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer depends on the function.  Is the return value a null-terminated string?  An allocated string that must be freed later?  Can it contain embedded nulls?  For the `mybuffer` parameter, will the contents be mutable?  Provide a simple implementation in C of the function, and your attempt at calling it with Python.  See [mcve].

Comment: Also, if your data comes from a binary file, you shouldn't use *c\_char\_p* (but *POINTER(c\_char)*).

Comment: @MarkTolonen yes, the return will be a null terminated string with no embedded nulls (the return value is not a problem to handle in other cases where I've used c-python interactions).  The challenge I'm having is identifying the proper argument as well as conversions for arbitrary binary data as input to the called c-function.  No, the input data will not be mutated in anyway by either caller or callee. I'll update to a more complete example later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your commented description, you can just use the obvious types if you don't need to free the returned `char*` memory.  You can pass a `bytes` object to a `void*`.  Here's a quick demo:

**test.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

API char* myfunc(void *mybuffer, int buflen) {
    const uint8_t* tmp = (const uint8_t*)mybuffer;
    for(int i = 0; i < buflen; ++i) // show the passed bytes
        printf("%02X\n", tmp[i]);
    return "output"; // static string no deallocation required
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct
import os

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.myfunc.argtypes = ct.c_void_p, ct.c_int
dll.myfunc.restype = ct.c_char_p

buf = bytes([1,2,0,0xaa,0x55])  # including embedded null
ret = dll.myfunc(buf, len(buf))
print(ret)
```

Output:

```
01
02
00
AA
55
b'output'
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize you could hand in a straight bytes object with no other changes like that to a void* arg. Much appreciated.